# Pandas Checking For Equality Too Slow for use

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a requirement to check records that change from one DataFrame to Another. It must match on *all* columns.

one is an excel file (`new_df`), one is a SQL Query (`sql_df`). The shape is ~20,000 rows by 39 columns. I thought this would be a good job for [`df.equals(other_df)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html)

Currently I am using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : [10,0,30,50,0,0,4,10,1,3], 
                    'D' : [1,0,3,4,0,0,7,8,0,1],
                    'E' : ['Universtiy of New York','New Hampshire University','JMU','Oklahoma State','Penn State',
                          'New Mexico Univ','Rutgers','Indiana State','JMU','University of South Carolina']})

sql_df= pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : [10,0,30,50,0,0,4,10,1,0], 
                    'D' : [5,0,3,4,0,0,7,8,0,1],
                    'E' : ['Universtiy of New York','New Hampshire University','NYU','Oklahoma State','Penn State',
                          'New Mexico Univ','Rutgers','Indiana State','NYU','University of South Carolina']})

# creates an empty list to append to
differences = []
# for all the IDs in the dataframe that should not change check if this record is the same in the database
# must use reset_index() so the equals() will work as I expect it to
# if it is not the same, append to a list which has the Aspn ID that is failing, along with the columns that changed
for unique_id in new_df['ID'].tolist():
# get the id from the list, and filter both sql and new dfs to this record
    if new_df.loc[new_df['ID'] == unique_id].reset_index(drop=True).equals(sql_df.loc[sql_df['ID'] == unique_id].reset_index(drop=True)) is False:
        bad_columns = []
        for column in new_df.columns.tolist():
        # if not the same above, check which column using the same logic
            if new_df.loc[new_df['ID'] == unique_id][column].reset_index(drop=True).equals(sql_df.loc[sql_df['ID'] == unique_id][column].reset_index(drop=True)) is False:
                bad_columns.append(column)                            
        differences.append([unique_id, bad_columns])
```

I later take `differences` and `bad_columns` and do other tasks with them.

There are many loops which I hope to avoid... as this may be the cause of my performance issue. It currently takes over 5 minutes for 20,000 records (will  vary on hardware), which is abysmal performance. I was thinking adding/concatenating all the columns into one long string to compare instead, but that seems like another inefficient way. What would be a better way of solving this/how can I avoid this messy appending to an empty list solution?

Comment: What makes you think `equals` is the culprit?

Comment: @user2357112 - valid point. Could *easily* be the amount of looping - i updated the title to be less misleading about this

Comment: A sample from both `new_df` and `sql_df` (or something looking alike) would greatly help to provide a working solution.

Comment: @FabienP, Updated, but really it can be any two dataframes with the same columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [26]: new_df.ne(sql_df)
Out[26]:
       B      C      D      E     ID
0  False  False   True  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False   True  False
3  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False  False
6   True  False  False  False  False
7  False  False  False  False  False
8  False  False  False   True  False
9  False   True  False  False  False
```

Show dissimilar columns:

```
In [27]: new_df.ne(sql_df).any(axis=0)
Out[27]:
B      True
C      True
D      True
E      True
ID    False
dtype: bool
```

Show dissimilar rows:

```
In [28]: new_df.ne(sql_df).any(axis=1)
Out[28]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
```

**UPDATE:**

showing dissimilar cells:

```
In [86]: x = new_df.ne(sql_df)

In [87]: new_df[x].loc[x.any(1)]
Out[87]:
    B    C    D    E  ID
0 NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN NaN
2 NaN  NaN  NaN  JMU NaN
6 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
8 NaN  NaN  NaN  JMU NaN
9 NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN NaN

In [88]: sql_df[x].loc[x.any(1)]
Out[88]:
    B    C    D    E  ID
0 NaN  NaN  5.0  NaN NaN
2 NaN  NaN  NaN  NYU NaN
6 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
8 NaN  NaN  NaN  NYU NaN
9 NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN NaN
```

Comment: There are always these secret little pandas methods that I didn't even know existed even when searching through the documentation. I'll see if I can make this work. This technically answers my original question so I will accept for SO health. What would be the way to get the ID or `loc` of the dissimilar columns/rows?

Comment: @MattR, do you want to show only dissimilar cells or the whole dissimilar rows/columns?

Comment: @MaxU, I guess the aim is to produce something similar to `differences.append([unique_id, bad_columns])` (see last part of the sample code from the question) which looks like a sequence with `ID` and a list of the names of columns with a difference.

Comment: @MaxU, I would like to show the ID and columns that are not equal, for each ID.

Answer (score 2):

Get filtered dataframe showing only rows with differences:

```
result_df = new_df[new_df != sql_df].dropna(how='all')

>>> result_df
Out[]:
    B    C    D    E  ID
0 NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN NaN
2 NaN  NaN  NaN  JMU NaN
8 NaN  NaN  NaN  JMU NaN
9 NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN NaN
```

Get tuples of `ID` and columns names where there is a difference, which is the output you where trying to produce.
This should work even if you have several columns with difference for the same `ID`.

```
result_df.set_axis(labels=new_df.ID[result_df.index], axis=0)

>>> result_df.apply(lambda x: (x.name, result_df.columns[x.notnull()]), axis=1)
Out[]:
ID
0    (0, [D])
2    (2, [E])
8    (8, [E])
9    (9, [C])
dtype: object
```

Please note that `apply` is close to a `for` loop, so the second part will likely take more time than the first.

Comment: Great Answer. I will test this out as well!

Comment: I am getting a sytax error in the first line of code, new_df.[new... is there supposed to be a .loc? I am also facing `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects` as in my real-world example the two dataframes do not have the same amount of records. Even adding a reset_index does not solve the `ValueError` any advice there?

Comment: Update: I removed the `.` to remove the Sytnax error as well as filtered both Dataframes to where they both have the same ID. this works beautifully. Would it be possible to explain how `result_df.set_axis` is working The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) don't explain very well?

Comment: @MattR, fixed the typo, thanks! `result_df.set_axis` will replace `axis=0` (the index) of `result_df` with the provided data. Here `new_df.ID[result_df.index]` is the values of `ID` where there is difference.